# If AS works as an alias in SQL then shouldn't it work in a function?

Tags: sql

From what I've gathered this

```
SELECT 
  people.id, 
  people.name,
  COUNT(sales.sale) AS sale_count,
  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sale_rank DESC) AS sale_rank
FROM people 
JOIN sales ON people.id = sales.people_id
GROUP BY people.id 
ORDER BY sale_count DESC;
```

should mean that `COUNT(sales.sale)` is the same as `sale_count` yet the example only works if I use 
`RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(sales.sale) DESC) AS sale_rank`

Is this how AS always works or could this be because I'm doing the "SQL Basics: Simple JOIN and RANK" kata on Codewars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how SQL works.  In general, a column alias defined in a `SELECT` cannot be used later in that `SELECT` (or in the `WHERE` or `FROM` clauses).

The reason is simple:  SQL does not guarantee the ordering of expressions in a `SELECT`.   Hence, the definition and the use could be in any order.

Note:  There are some databases that allow column aliases for window functions.  Clearly, you are not using one of those.